# ListBox Datasource Won't Update (Windows Application)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, listbox

I've looked through almost every other thread about this topic with zero results. I have a ListBox I'm using for a log display of sorts. The console updates correctly by both displaying the needed information and properly increment the size of the Items list. "Log Beginning" and "Log #2" also display properly in the ListBox. Also, the "Written" state is being reached correctly. Anybody have any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
public BindingList<string> Items;

public Form1()
    {
        Items = new BindingList<string>();
        Items.Add("Log Beginning");
        InitializeComponent();
        Items.Add("Log #2");
        LBLog.DataSource = Items;
        Connect(); // leads to a websocket delcaration, irrelevant here
    }

...

private void websocket_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received " + sender.ToString() + " : " + e.ToString());

        WriteLog("Log: " + e.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("Log size: " + Items.Count);


    }
private void WriteLog(String msg)
    {
        Items.Add("test");

        LBLog.DataSource = null; // tried adding these two, shouldn't need for a binding list
        LBLog.DataSource = Items;


        Console.WriteLine("Written");

    }
```

Comment: @LarsTech I'm already using a BindingList, see my code

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  The code you posted doesn't duplicate the problem then.  Are you trying to update that list in a different thread?

Comment: Is there some reason the `WriteLog` method never uses the string `msg` passed to it?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue. I was unknowingly trying to update it from a different thread. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c?rq=1) helped me solve my problem.